# Tableau Buttons not working in server

Tags: tableau-api

I am creating a set of Tableau dashboards and I want to change from dashboard to dashboard using shapes. I followed this tutorial on creating a [navigation page](http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/table-of-contents-creation-to-navigate-to-other-dashboards) and it worked on the Tableau application, but once I upload the data into the server, the buttons stop working.

Comment: Is the option "Show Sheets as Tabs" enabled?

Comment: I actually want to avoid using tabs, and use shapes as buttons to switch between dashboards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable show sheet as tabs when you publish dashboard in tableau sever or you can enable this option later in tableau server option.

Without enabled sheet as tabs button will not work.

Comment: Thanks!! This words. Is there a way to hide the tabs and use only buttons?

Comment: Till now there is no option available for it